# Generating a key pair for Google Compute

Tags: google-compute-engine, ssh-keys

In this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#generatesshkeypair) there is the following:

[image]

May I know what "Google username" it is refering to?

Then in the next sentence in the same paragraph it talks about the key structure. Is this related to the `Key Comment`? What are we to do about the key structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username there refers to the linux username of the user on the Google Compute Engine VM instance you're going to ssh into.

Let's assume the desired username is `oldgeezer` on the VM.

- Set the Key comment to `oldgeezer`
- The generated key should have the following key structure `ssh-rsa [KEY_VALUE] oldgeezer`

This information is clearly mentioned in the steps for `linux` but not in the steps for Windows using `puttygen` unfortunately.

> where [USERNAME] is the user on the instance for whom you will apply
>   the key